# Make Outlook look like Thunderbird?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

For some strange and irrelevant reason, I am currently consigned to using Microsoft Outlook on Windows on some computer. Now, I'm used to Mozilla Thunderbird, which has a bunch of shortcomings and failures, but at least has a decent main mail window interface: Nice, lean and dense; and one line per message. To be more concrete, here's the layout I have configured on Thunderbird:

[image]

Is it possible - through configuration or other means - to make Outlook's main window interface be more like in Thunderbird, at least in the terms of the appearance of the main mail window?

Comment: Thunderbird has no single look. Please describe in more detail what you’re expecting in terms of overall window layout, list entries and maybe button positions. Also, which version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: It's unlikely outlook to have a "thunderbird look" option. Other solution would be an add in, but that's off topic being software recommendation.

Comment: @DanielB: See edit.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: If the way to achieve something is installing an add-in, that's actually on-topic for an answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Outlook 2016 or something close to it:

1. In the ribbon's "View" tab, select "Reading Pane → Bottom" (or Off if you like). This will automatically switch the message list to a more traditional single-line view.
2. In the same "View" tab, select "Message Preview → Off".
3. Optionally, click "View Settings → Other Settings" to disable grouping by date and hide grid lines between messages.

   (You'll also find an option there which re-enables the compact message list if the window is too narrow; you can disable it and select "Always use single-line layout".)
4. Click "Change View → Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders" to make the settings global. (Note that some settings, such as message previews, are global on their own.)
5. Optionally, double-click any ribbon tab title to collapse the ribbon.
6. Edit: Oh, and choose the "Folders" view in the bottom-left switcher, so that you get something resembling folder icons instead of the boring text-only list.

[image: Screenshot of the resulting layout]

Comment: Can I also disable the categorization by date, i.e. the header lines saying "Date: Today", "Date: Yesterday" and so on?

Comment: Yes, in the same "View Settings → Other Settings" next to the grid lines option.

Comment: ... and can I make these changes, including the gridlines, apply to other mail folders? universally?

Comment: That's (probably) in the "Change View" dropdown. You might have to edit an existing predefined view.

Answer (score -1):

The biggest missing feature in Outlook that I couldn't live without are the Tabs at the top which like in a browser can be used for individual messages you want to return to or even other account inboxes.

Check out the Owl addin not free but cheap and worth if for Thunderbird fan.